# c++ function that can't return a meaningful value under some conditions

Tags: c++, function, pointers, null

I have a member function with an object type as the return value type:

```
MyObject myfunction(parameters) {
    if (some condition) { 
        return MyObject(parameters);
    } else { 
        ... no valid object can be created ... 
    } 
}
```

Under certain conditions (checked for in the function body) an object of type MyObject cannot be created and returned.

Beeing just an occasional c++ programmer I can spontaneously come up with three solutions:

1. Changing the return value type to * MyObject and returning nullptr if no valid object can be created (C++11), then checking for equality to nullptr in the calling code.
2. Throwing an exception if no object can be created and catching that one in the calling code.
3. Creating an object with some values that I define as invalid and check for that before using the returned object.

What would be the standard way of dealing with such a situation and the best solution in terms of performance? ... or some obvious work-around that I just don't see ...

A state-of-the-art C++11 solution would be perfect :-)

My thoughts so far:
Solution 1 seems OK, but is C++11 only and I would have to create the returned object on the heap in order to be able to pass it to the main program (returning the object itself to the calling function, thus keeping it in the stack might be quicker for small objects?).
Solution 2 might be slower and leads to verbose coding in the main program.
Solution 3 is probably the slowest (an object is created in vain) and not very convenient to check for in the main program.

For my code no valid return object is rather the default situation than the exception and the created object is rather small, but general considerations considering different cases are certainly useful for other readers' applications ...

Thanks a lot to all of you for help :-)

Comment: I have no idea what a `myfunction` does, and I have no idea what a `MyObject` is. How can I give you a best solution?

Comment: Usually I would say nullptr, but it really depends on your project.

Comment: IOW, there is no best solution. There are several solutions that work great in some of the various different combinations of the possible answers to "what does `myfunction` do?" and "what is a `MyObject`?". TL;DR don't stop thinking.

Comment: If you really need to return instances instead of pointers in this function throwing an exception would be the correct way IMHO

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: True, but I intended to keep it simple and as general as possible.

Comment: What is the purpose of myFunction?  Does it exist just so you can do something different in the failure case?  An alternative to all three options above might be to simply throw an exception in MyObject's constructor under certain circumstances.

Comment: @datamole the problem is that those two goals are contradictory, at least from the point-of-view of someone answering: as simple as possible would have been one very specific example; as general as possible would not ask for a best solution, but for what would be the main driving motivations behind a decision. As is, this is not a simple question (there are just too many relevant variables to consider) and is not a general question (it asks for the one best solution, so it can't possibly apply to many cases)

Comment: Another option not listed is taking a "destination" MyObjec by reference, and returning a bool if the function succeeded.  This is how things work in C, and how iostreams work.  I dont recommend it for most cases though.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: MyObject has two int coordinates and a bool value, myfunction() is a member function of MyObject and takes a MyObject as a parameter in oder to calculate intersections of two MyObject instances. Thus the Objects are pretty slim really except from a couple of member functions that are implemented.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: I don't deny that you're kind of right there :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All 3 of your suggested solutions are valid and common, depending on the circumstances.

If being unable to create the object is an error condition that is likely to cause the calling function to have to abort, back up and retry, or take other drastic measures, then throw an exception.

If inability to create the object is a routine event, and you expect the caller to check if an object was created and proceed fairly normally in either case, returning null is a good solution.

If there's a reasonable dummy or blank object that can be created, that's a fine solution. But this is pretty rare. You should only do this if the caller will actually process the dummy object.

If you return a null pointer and then you find that every place you call this function you are writing

```
MyObject* myobject=myfunction(whatever);
if (myobject==null) throw new PanicException;
```

Then you might as well just throw the exception inside the function.

Worse, if you are writing:

```
MyObject* myobject=myfunction(whatever);
if (myobject!=null)
{
  ... process it ...
}
else
{
   ... display error message ...
}
```

Then you are just simulating exception handling with an IF statement. Use a real exception.

On the other hand, if you throw an exception and then you find you are regularly writing:

```
MyObject* myobject;
try
{
  myobject=myfunction(whatever);
}
catch (PanicException pe)
{
  myobject=null;
}
```

Well then, you would have been better off to just return the null.

I've occasionally created dummy objects. The most common case is when a function returns a collection, like an array or linked list, and if I find no data to put in the collection, then return a collection with zero elements. Then the caller loops through the elements in the collection, and if there are none, that's just fine. I've had a few cases where I've returned an object with a zero-length string for the name or customer id or whatever. But in general, if you're just returning a dummy object so that the caller can test and say, oh, it's a dummy object, and then throw it away, I think you're better off to return null.

BTW not sure what you meant when you said that you could only return a null pointer in C++11. The ability to pass around nulls goes back to the earliest version of C++ that I ever saw.

Comment: 'nullptr' didnt exist in C++11, but 'NULL' did.

Answer (score 7):

In the usual case, returning a [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) works:

```
boost::optional<MyObject> myfunction(parameters) {
    if (some condition) { 
        return MyObject(parameters);
    } else { 
        return boost::none;
    } 
}
```

And at the call site:

```
auto ret = myfunction(...);
if(ret)
  // use '*ret'  or 'ret.get()'
```

But as R. Martinho mentions, there are drawbacks to this solution (namely, move-only types don't work because Boost.Optional is not yet updated to support move-semantics).

Comment: Doesn't work if you want to avoid the boost library either.  It would be fairly easy to write an equivalent type, however.  I think this is the best idea if: (a) the objects are small, so creating on the heap is suboptimal; and (b) being unable to create the object is common.  If failure to create the object is rare, then it makes more sense to throw an exception.

Comment: @PeterRuderman: What does size have to do with anything here? I really wouldn't recommend creating stuff on the heap in any case, except where you risk stack overflow from big objects. Also, there's no reason to avoid Boost, really.

Comment: @Xeo: If "MyObject" is small, then creating it on the heap would be quite wasteful (especially if he has to create a large number of these objects).  On the other hand, creating a large objects on the stack can also be non-performant if the object has to be copied and/or moved afterwards.

Comment: @Xeo:  beuracracy at work can be a good reason to avoid boost.

Comment: @Peter: Copy elision should take care of that 99% of the time.

Comment: @Mooing: Okay, maybe I should've said "there's no *rational* reason to avoid Boost". :/

Comment: @Xeo: You're assuming that the returned object is used only in the calling function.  What if the caller has to store it or pass it to someone else?

Comment: @MooingDuck: regarding Boost.Option, I would note that it is quite full-featured (especially the in-place things which predate move semantics). In C++11, implementing a light-weight Boost.Option is trivial, especially using `std::aligned_storage` as... storage. So whether to use Boost might be an issue, but it's not a valid reason to reject the *idea* of the optional type.

Answer (score 4):

Since your question is phrased in generalities, I will also respond in generalities.

If you have a function whose job it is to create and return an object, then *that* is it's job.

Now if you want to design this function in such a way so that when certian conditions needed to build the object are *not* met then not return the object, you have actually changed the semantics of this function.  Now instead on just one responsibility, it has three:

1. Determine if the right conditions exist to construct the object
2. If yes, construct and return the object
3. If no, return nothing, or some condition value that indicates non-creation

The "[Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)"  suggests that in general, good design dictates that one function (or class or what have you) should have one job to do.  Here, your function has three.

I would suggest that none of your suggested approaches is best in general.  Rather, I would go with:

> 4: Implement a separate function to determine the eligibility to
>   construct the object. If that function returns true, then call
>   `myFunction` which constructs the object & returns it.

Comment: I heartily... disagree. Your use of SRP is too rigid here: you can certainly pre-validate that the parameters are in the right state, but for **Defensive Programming* mandates that the function make that check too, just in case it has been forgotten, and you are back to square one => how should the function behave if the parameters are not right ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.:  Sure, you're right of course that the code should be defensive.  However if the function is called to create an object but it can't, I would consider that to be an exceptional circumstance.  Following this, I would throw an exception when this is the case.  Preferably from the constructor of the object in question itself.

Comment: But then your constructor is doing two things: deciding if it can build the object, and building the object. You're again right back where you started. I agree with the idea of single responsibility in general, but if you try to separate "process parameters" from "validate parameters", I think you're carrying the idea too far. What next? A function cannot both build an object AND return it, because that would be two things? In practice, we often most naturally discover that we cannot do something when we try to do it. Like, read record with a certain key ... oops, record not found ...

Comment: ... Calculate order total ... oops, order limit exceeded. Etc. If we try to write a pre-check for these things, we're going to end up writing a lot of the code twice: Once to do the calculation or look up or whatever so we can test if it's possible, then again to actually do the work. I'd rather do each thing once.

Answer (score 2):

The first solution should be used except if the conditions that prevent the creation of the object are **exceptional**. Otherwise returning a NULL pointer is a perfectly valid solution... even in C++11.

The "pointer" should of course be wrapped using an RAII container such as a std::unique_ptr. Should be common practice for you code really.

The third solution is a total waste of resources if you ask me. You would have to create an invalid (not useful) object, and copy it for the return value... only for it to be discarded.

Comment: Returning a pointer has the drawback that ownership is no longer clear nor enforced by the compiler. *Even in C++03*.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Okay good point, I should have specified a std::unique_ptr, rather than a raw pointer.

Comment: Note that returning by value will usually not copy the object, because of RVO: Return Value Optimization. As such your objection to the third solution is only partially valid: if the object is cheap to create, no resource is wasted. The real objection to the 3rd solution is one of semantics: objects with a "null" state can be harder to manipulate because of looser class invariants.